# Hand holding for my first wall/ceiling painting DIY with pictures of water damage

Tags: repair, painting, water-damage, repainting

[image: Water damage in corner of room]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I had some water damage in the corner of the room right as we were getting ready to put the house on the market.  I was planning on using a spackle or joint compound to cover the area where the 2 pieces of drywall meet.  Sand, texture, and then paint without primer.

My question is am I missing an vital steps?  It galls me that I have to paint 2 large walls and a 17' x 3' piece of the ceiling, but from everything i have read it is going to be needed as there isn't a way to just repair and paint this corner of the room.

Any other advice is definitely welcome as I am sure I don't even know what the correct questions to ask would be.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to do this without a primer. A shellac-based primer will help cover the water stain as well as help a topcoat adhere to the patching compound. Without it, there's a good chance the repair will be visible and the stain may bleed through eventually.

Comment: Can we assume the source of the leak has been repaired?  If not, not much sense of repairing/painting drywall.  Just painting a small patch job will be the first thing buyers notice.  New paint seems to look better on walls/ceilings than old paint.  Paint gets faded, collects dust over the years.

Comment: Do I need to use primer on the entire ceilings and walls or just where the stains and repairs are located?

The leak has been repaired.

Comment: Usually just a stain hiding primer on the patch/stain area.  The rest will want a good cleaning at least to remove dust/dirt/oils, unless you want to watch the new paint to peel off in wide strips.

Comment: Ok.  So the steps i should take are:


*Clean up the damaged area, removing peeling paint and other damage  

*Spackle the water damaged drywall  

*Texture the area using joint compound or spray texture  

*Clean the walls and ceiling to remove dust and dirt with a soapy water mixture and 
soft sponges  

*Prime the stained and repaired areas with a neutral primer  

*Paint the walls and ceiling  

I appreciate all the advice.  Thank you.

Comment: No. *Clean up the damaged area, removing peeling paint and other damage *prime the patch area with stain-blocking primer *Spackle the water damaged drywall *Texture the area using joint compound or spray texture *Clean the walls and ceiling to remove dust and dirt with a soapy water mixture and soft sponges *Prime the stained and repaired areas with a stain-blocking primer *Paint the walls and ceiling.

Comment: gnicko,  crip659, Jimmy Fix-it - All of your input has been invaluable.  Thank you.